# Apex trigger error: Illegal assignment from String to Name

Tags: apex, soql

In my trigger I need to assign the owner of a record to a specific queue.

So here I am trying to retrieve the queue ID and set the owner of the record

```
string sQueueId = [select Id from Group where Name = 'Systems Change Request' and Type = 'Queue'].Id;
rq.Owner=sQueueId;
```

I guess `string sQueueId` should be something else, but what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Id sQueueId = [select Id from Group where Name = 'Systems Change Request' and Type = 'Queue' LIMIT 1][0].Id;
rq.OwnerId = sQueueId;
```

First of all you're getting `.Id` at the end of your query and trying to assign it to a String, whereas I think you should make it of data type "Id" rather than "String".

You then just needed to assign that Id to OwnerId, rather than Owner. I think Owner is a Name field.

If you tried to assign the String to OwnerId, I think you'd get the "error trying to assign Name to Id" or somesuch.

**Edit**:
I'm not totally sure that if in case your query returned more than 1 row or you need to specifically identify which row you want to get the Id of, you should put `[0]` between your query and `.Id` too and probably limit your query to get only 1 record as well. Unsure of exactly what the best practise is here but this should work.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is right but instead of rq.Owner=sQueueId; , replace it with rq.OwnerId=sQueueId; and it should work.
Thanks 
BK